# Not able to call javascript from xsl

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I am trying to call inline js function from within my xsl file but it is not giving intended output.

PFB my code:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="js"> 


function calTime()
{
return 129;
}

</msxsl:script>
```

Real Output:

```
 function calTime()
    {
    return 129;
    }
```

Desired Output:

```
129
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you calling `calTime` within your file? You'd need to use something like `<xsl:value-of select="js.calTime()"/>` within your file to get the return value of the function ([src](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx))

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? How does the complete sample look? Only some Microsoft XSLT processors like MSXML or XslCompiledTransform support that extension element but it is necessary to use the proper namespace of course and you have not event shown us which namespace you use.

Comment: Hi I am using this :
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript"   exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl js">
  @MartinHonnen

Comment: Which software do you use to run the XSLT code?

Comment: Hi I am using 
 <xsl:value-of select="js:calTime()"/>to call js function @BrandonBoone

Comment: I am working on TeamSite 7.3 SP (WCM )tool @MartinHonnen

Comment: I don't know which XSLT processor your tool TeamSite uses. What does http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest.xml output for your tool?

Comment: I also now wrote http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/msScriptTest3.xml to test for support of extension functions done with JScript or VB(Script).